# Is there a reduction in storage using short-hand hex vs normal hex vs color name in CSS?

Tags: css

Just curious, of the physical bits taken.  I understand that the difference in size is negligible.

For example

```
color: #0f0;
```

vs.

```
color: #00ff00;
```

vs.

```
Color: lime;
```

What about something as crazy as:

`color: LightGoldenRodYellow;`  *real color name*

vs.

`color: #FAFAD2;` *light Golden Rod's hex*

**Can anyone do a number crunch?**

Comment: size vs support: that's the real issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple, whichever has the fewest number of characters is the smallest.

The number of bits taken depends on encoding. It is always at least 1 byte per character, with common modern encodings.

Comment: with this logic; therefore: Color: lime; is less than color: #00ff00;

Comment: ....because it is. For the default encoding in gedit? 14 bytes for color, 16 for the hex. The only way you could get the hex shorter is color:#0f0;

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about which is shortest. Just run your CSS through a minifier like AjaxMin http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/ and it will output the shortest CSS for you and save your bits.

Comment: While I agree that a minifier is generally going to be a lot easier, you can potentially save a few characters with this trick if you know it.  For instance, if I'm using a color `#01fd01` but I'm okay with changing the color very slightly to `#00ff00` in order to allow me to minify that to `#0f0`, the minifier can't do that for me automatically since it would be changing my color.

Comment: For something like that, you can write a filter with a difference mechanism. (e.g. If +/-2 for each pairing, adjust to a version that can be shortened). It is just not a common case/rule for minifiers.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much to "crunch".  (depending on character set) Each character is one byte (or more), count the characters and there you go.

`color: #0f0;` is 12 bytes where as `color: #00ff00;` is 15, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, always go with the shorthand.

For one rule, the difference is negligible.

But over the course of the entire stylesheet, it will add up!

Plus, you don't need the space in between `color` and the code.  Save yourself a bunch of bits by writing `color:#0f0;` instead.